# file not found while running pyspark program

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

im new to pyspark and i want to lunch a pyspark program in standalone cluster, i followed the steps on this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-apache-pyspark-on-windows-10-f5f0c506bea1#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20work%20with,back%20to%20the%20Command%20Prompt.) and i lunched my program using this command:

`bin\spark-submit examples\src\main\python\LSI_MapReduce\LSI.py`
here is the part of my code where the error is happening:

```
# load the dataset 
rows = np.loadtxt('first.txt') <----- here

rows = sc.parallelize(rows)
mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# compute SVD 
svd = mat.computeSVD(20, computeU=True)
```

the first steps of my code did run fine and i got this error:

```
in the line 200 FileNotFoundError: first.txt not found.
```

`LSI_MapReduce`folder has a file named **first.txt** at the same place as `LSI.py`

when i run my program on **VScode** it works perfectly.

**how can i fix this error ?**

i highely would appriciate any help .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is some issue with the root directory where you execute spark-submit?

Comment: where should i execute the spark-submit ?

Comment: the thing is the start of the program works fine i get the outputs and everything but when it reach the loading of the text file the error appears even tho it is at the same level as the program (no inside folders or anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python, via Numpy, (not Spark) is trying to read the file from where you run your Python interpreter,

The word count example in the link reads the README.md file next to the bin folder, so if that's where you start the command, that's where your file needs to be. Otherwise, cd down into the example folder where your file exists

Also, Spark can read text files or csv files itself; so you shouldn't need numpy to do that